# Radiogroup setup

Tags: android

In setting up a radio group in java file, when I try to pass use setOnCheckedChanngeListener method then it is calling for the compund button but i want for the radio button. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Any code? its difficult do determine the problem without seeing what is happening

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, this is the solution:

The `CompoundButton` you receive in your listener method is a `RadioButton` so you can cast it:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)buttonView;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am unable to use OnCheckedChangeListener() method for the radio group. It says "The method setOncheckedChangeListener(tutorialOne) is undefined for the type RadioButton".

Comment: I dont know how to upload photos here.!

Comment: The type of tutorialOne must be `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` (this can be confusing with `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`)